# How to use content of a string variable to refer to a "string defined" key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am currently trying to make a battle system where different types have weaknesses. These weaknesses are stored in a dictionary under their "master type" as a string value for the key. I'm trying to use another variable which has the exact same String Format (I.E i.e if the key I wanted was "Normal", then the other variable is also "Normal".

However, when I try to use the .get() method with this other variable inside it, it just returns a "NoneType" value and throws all my code off.

Below is the code that I am using to load the values into the dictionary.

```
def weakness_load():
    pokeweakness.seek(0)
    dump = pokeweakness.read().split("\n")
    for i in dump:
        print(i)
        if i != "":
            basetype,allbaseweaknesses = i.split(",")
            print(basetype,allbaseweaknesses)
            weakness_dict[basetype] = allbaseweaknesses
            print(weakness_dict[basetype])
            print("\n")
```

And Below is the code that I am using to see if the defender's type is weak to the attackers type.

```
def check_weakness(attack,defender,mover):
    defweakness = weakness_dict.get(defender)
    print(defweakness)
    if attack in defweakness:
        plattackcrit = False
        aiattackcrit = False
        if mover == 1:
            plattackcrit = True
            return(plattackcrit)
        elif mover == 2:
            aiattackcrit = True
            return(aiattackcrit)
```

The above code fails when it gets to

> if attack in defweakness:

Because of a "TypeError: argument of type: 'NoneType' is not iterable."

Sample data for dictionary:

> Key: Rock || Data: Fighting;Steel;Ground;Water;Grass;

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not quite sure how I can get around this and I'm struggling to find any content around this online too.

Comment: What is Defender, how do you call check_weakness? Also I don't get your dictionary. Do you have two keys called Key and Data? What does || signify?

Comment: Furthermore, you split on comma (,), but your data seems to use semi colon (;)

Comment: "defender" is the type of whichever player is defending from an attack. For instance if the defending player's type is normal, then `defender = "Normal"`.

"check_weakness" is called as such: `plattackcrit = check_weakness(plmovetype,aitype1,1)` where "plmovetype" is the type that the attacker's move is; "aitype1" is the defender's main type, and the "1" represents the function going into the first 'if' statement, not the second 'elif' statement.

I should have formatted the sample data better:
`'Rock': 'Fighting;Steel;Ground;Water;Grass`

Comment: The ; are just there to separate the other types that the master type (the type defined as the key) is weak to. They have no further relevance rather than just making it more clear to read the data stored under that key.

Comment: How does the check_weakness function know what the weakness_dict is? Maybe you should pass it as a parameter? It's hard to say what's going on without more context about how the functions are called.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. That's the issue, I never returned the updated dictionary once the function was complete. I've fixed it now and it works. Muchos Gracias randomer64.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Like a complete idiot, I forgot to return `weakness_dict` so I never actually had the updated dictionary stored.

I made sure to update the "weakness_load()" function to `return weakness_dict` and also added `weakness_dict = weakness_load()` just before I call upon my main code so that it's all loaded before the code runs.